# How do I resolve an non-secure connection on Heroku, despite my SSL certificate being valid?

Tags: ssl, heroku

I've deployed a webapp on heroku with a `hobby dyno`. I'm using Heroku's ACM to manage the SSL. Despite this, I'm receiving a non-secure connection warning from Chrome.

***Any suggestions on how to resolve this?***

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Wow...* This was simple: A url in my css was using `http://` instead of `https://`...

*Fixing this resolved the issue.*